# Asp.net core inject ApplicationDBContext into service layer

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm new to .Net core, I'm trying to inject `ApplicationDBContext` into service layer but it doesn't work.

Here are services configuration (`ConfigureServices`):

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IApplicationEventService, ApplicationEventService>();
services.AddScoped<ILoginHistoryService, LoginHistoryService>();
services.AddScoped<IApplicationEventHandler<UserLogedInEvent>, HandleUserLogedIn>();
```

And the constructor of `LoginHistoryService`:

```cs
public LoginHistoryService(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
   _Context = context;
}
```

When the user logged in, `AccountController` raise application event:

```cs
await _eventService.Raise<UserLogedInEvent>(new UserLogedInEvent(user, DateTime.UtcNow));
```

But the ApplicationEventService throws an excpetion when it try to resolve required event handler:

```cs
var allInstance = _ServiceProvider.GetServices<IApplicationEventHandler<T>>();
```

and the error message is:

> Cannot resolve 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[App.Interfaces.IApplicationEventHandler`1[App.Web.Infrastructure.Events.UserLogedInEvent]]'
>   from root provider because it requires scoped service
>   'App.Interfaces.IApplicationEventHandler`1[App.Web.Infrastructure.Events.UserLogedInEvent]'.

Please help and advise.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with your context or services. The exception is explicit. Something is using `IApplicationEventHandler` and you haven't registered a concrete type with the DI container to handle that. So do so. What's the confusion here?

Comment: But, as you can see above I already registered 'IApplicationEventHandler' with the DI container and actually I couldn't find why this error happened.